# Not able to get query string

Tags: asp.net

I am using the below code for setting URL in the current http context

```
public HttpContext SetNewHttpContext(string uRL)
    {
        var httpRequest = new HttpRequest("", uRL, "");
        var httpResponse = new HttpResponse(new StringWriter());         
        return new HttpContext(httpRequest, httpResponse);
    }
```

Invoking it as under

```
HttpContext.Current = SetNewHttpContext("http://root/test.aspx?userid=319279549&name=xyz");

var val =  HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["userid"];
```

But i am not able to get the value of the querystring(userid here) and getting null.

Why?

Please help

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Actually i am creating a unit test project for which i need to produce a fake url..

Comment: In that case, I would use `HttpContextBase` and a mocking framework. There are a [number of questions on this topic](http://www.bing.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+mock+httpcontext&go=&qs=n&sk=&form=QBRE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   Uri tempUri = new Uri("http://root/test.aspx?userid=319279549&name=xyz"); 
   string sQuery = tempUri.Query;

   NameValueCollection queryString =
                System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(sQuery ,Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: what will be returned if that field is null?

Comment: are you sure that your context has these parameters in them. Maybe something is clearing it before you read it